# Mass file download - Drive API .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

Question:

How can I tell my backup tool to download all the files it recorded in fileids?

The method I'm using is C#/.NET https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#examples

I'll spare the boring details and say that part of my program logs in Once as each user (well, using the Apps Service API), grabs all their files' fileIds and records them to a flat text file. My program then opens that flat text file and begins downloading each fileId recorded for that user, but the problem is: it's soooo slow because it opens a new connection for a file, waits for the file to finish, then gets a new fileid and starts the whole process over again. It's not very efficient.

Google's example, which I copied pretty much Verbatim (I modified the vars a little bit by immediately grabbing and exporting their mimetype, so the first 3 lines are moot):

```
var fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

// Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
// It will notify on each chunk download and when the
// download is completed or failed.
request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
    (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
{
    switch(progress.Status)
    {
        case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
        {
            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
            break;
        }
        case DownloadStatus.Completed:
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
            break;
        }
        case DownloadStatus.Failed:
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
            break;
        }
    }
};
request.Download(stream);
```

Is there Any way I can streamline this so that my program can download all the files it knows for the user in one big handshake, vs reading a fileid individually, then opening a session, exporting, downloading, closing, then doing the same exact thing for the next file? Hope this makes sense.

Thank you for any help ahead of time!

--Mike

**---EDIT---**

I wanted to add more details so that hopefully what I'm looking to do makes more sense:

So what's happening in the following code is: I am creating a "request" that will let me export the filetype (which I have from the flat text file as the fileId[0], and the "mimetype" which is in the array as fileId[1].)
What's killing the speed of the program is having to build the "BuildService" request each time for each file.

```
foreach (var file in deltafiles)
{
    try
    {
    if (bgW.CancellationPending)
    {
        stripLabel.Text = "Backup canceled!";
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
        }
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string[] foldervalues = File.ReadAllLines(savelocation + "folderlog.txt");
        cnttototal++;
        bgW.ReportProgress(cnttototal);
        // Our file is a CSV. Column 1 = file ID, Column 2 = File name
        var values = file.Split(',');

        string fileId = values[0];
        string fileName = values[1];
        string mimetype = values[2];
        mimetype = mimetype.Replace(",", "_");
        string folder = values[3];
        int foundmatch = 0;
        int folderfilelen = foldervalues.Count();

        fileName = fileName.Replace('\\', '_').Replace('/', '_').Replace(':', '_').Replace('!', '_').Replace('\'', '_').Replace('*', '_').Replace('#', '_').Replace('[', '_').Replace(']', '_');

        var request = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Export(fileId, mimetype);

        //Default extensions for files. Not sure what this should be, so we'll null it for now.
        string ext = null;

        // Things get sloppy here. The reason we're checking MimeTypes
        // is because we have to export the files from Google's format
        // to a format that is readable by a desktop computer program
        // So for example, the google-apps.spreadsheet will become an MS Excel file.
        if (mimetype == mimeSheet || mimetype == mimeSheetRitz || mimetype == mimeSheetml)
        {
            request = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Export(fileId, exportSheet);
            ext = ".xls";
        }
        if (mimetype == mimeDoc || mimetype == mimeDocKix || mimetype == mimeDocWord)
        {
            request = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Export(fileId, exportDoc);
            ext = ".docx";
        }
        if (mimetype == mimePres || mimetype == mimePresPunch)
        {
            request = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Export(fileId, exportPres);
            ext = ".ppt";
        }
        if (mimetype == mimeForm || mimetype == mimeFormfb || mimetype == mimeFormDrawing)
        {
            request = CreateService.BuildService(user).Files.Export(fileId, exportForm);
            ext = ".docx";
        }
        // Any other file type, assume as know what it is (which in our case, will be a txt file)
        // apply the mime type and carry on.
        string dest = Path.Combine(savelocation, fileName + ext);
        var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        int oops = 0;
        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
        // download is completed or failed.

        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
        (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                {
                    throw new Exception("File may be corrupted.");
                    break;
                    }
                case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                    break;
                }
                case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                {
                    oops = 1;
                    logFile.WriteLine(fileName + " could not be downloaded. Possible Google draw/form OR bad name.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        request.Download(stream);
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
```

Is there any way I could streamline this process so I don't have to build the drive service Every time I want to download a file? The flat text file the program reads looks similar to

FILEID,ACTUAL FILE NAME,MIMETYPE

So is there any way I could cut out the middle man and feed the request.Download method without constantly reminding the "foreach" statement to export the file type as a file system-readable file? (good grief, sorry, I know this sounds like a lot.)

Any pointers would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the tutorial : [Google Drive API with C# .net – Download](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-download/). This is a much simpler code to download a file. Also there are other factors like intermittent internet connect that may affect the ETA of downloading the file.

Code Sample :

```
/// Download a file
/// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
/// 

/// a Valid authenticated DriveService
/// File resource of the file to download
/// location of where to save the file including the file name to save it as.
/// 
public static Boolean downloadFile(DriveService _service, File _fileResource, string _saveTo)
{

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl))
{
try
{
var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl );
byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes);
return true; 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
return false;
}
}
else
{
// The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
return false;
}
}
```

> Using `_service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync` we can pass it the download url of the file we would like to download. Once the file is download its a simple matter of wright the file to the disk.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the link :-) I did try referencing that earlier on when I was just starting, but I opted to go to drive sdk v3 as it looked like v2 was going to be "EOL" soon.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer as much as it is a work around, even then it's only half the answer (for right now.) I threw my gloves off and played dirty.

First, I updated my nuget google api packages to the latest version available today inside my VS project, then went to `https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client`, forked/cloned it, changed the Google.Apis.Drive.v3.cs file (which compiles to google.apis.drive.v3.dll) so that the mimetype is no longer read only (it can do get; and set;, when by default, it only allowed get).

Because I already knew the mime types, I am able to force assign the mime type now to the request and go on with my life, instead of having to build the client service, connect, only to export the file type that I already know it is.

It's not pretty, not how it should be done, but this was really bothering me!

Going back to @Mr.Rebot, I thank you again for your help and research! :-)